# В чём проблема ListView?

Tags: c#, wpf

Нужно представление нескольких элементов в виде значков. Использую ListView:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="FileItemStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="10,5"/>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left"/>
        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Top"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate  TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
                    <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top">
                        <ContentPresenter/>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</UserControl.Resources>

<ListView x:Name="listView" ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource FileItemStyle}">

    <ListView.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <WrapPanel/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemsPanel>

    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <DockPanel>
                <TextBlock DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                <Image DockPanel.Dock="Top" Height="48" Width="48" Source="{Binding Image}"/>
            </DockPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>

</ListView>
```

Как можно видеть, код внутри UserControl, т.к. представление будет основано не только на одном ListView. Проблема состоит в добавлении элементов:

```
        listView.Items.Add(new { Name = "Icon1", Image = ".\\Images\\icon.png" });
        listView.Items.Add(new { Name = "Icon2", Image = ".\\Images\\icon.png" });
```

Если добавить более 5 элементов, то выбрасывается исключение следующего содержания:

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException' occurred in PresentationFramework.dll

Additional information: Предоставление значения для "System.Windows.Baml2006.TypeConverterMarkupExtension" вызвало исключение.
```

Добавить 5, всё работает нормально. Именно это число было взято ввиду просто ширины listView - когда значки переходят на 2-ую "строчку" во wrappanel.
Т.е. не удаётся в несколько строк располагать значки.

Как проблему решить?

Comment: А можно побольше информации об исключении? Внутренние исключения, например. Надо ж понять, что именно вылетело.

Comment: Это вся информация что предоставляется об исключении.

Comment: Что-то Вы забыли указать. у меня все работает и при 100. Все переносит по строкам без проблем. Единственное что изменил <WrapPanel Width="..."/> (vs2013 community)

Comment: Как вы изменили ширину?
И не забудьте, что у меня всё это дело в UserControl (мб это как-то влияет).

Comment: Хотя знаете, проблема в моём проекте. Вот сейчас создал другой и в нём всё в точности такой же код работает. Вот хрен знает чё теперь делать и что это за хрень